# Time format weird behavior

Tags: go, datetime-format

This is a part of a bigger code. I am little confused that if I use any other digit in the below format it results in wrong values.

so instead of

```
fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05-07:00"))
```

if I try to use

```
 fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 12:04:05-04:00"))
```

Result is wrong. Even when it is same format, just digit change

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)


func main() {

    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05-07:00"))

}
```

So my question is why is it so. Digits inside format have no meaning. They are just for representation of the format.

Comment: What do you mean the digits have no meaning? They _are_ the representation of the format.

Comment: the digits inside Format, do they really make a difference whether 2006 or 2005 ?

Comment: Yes. How else would you differentiate the numbers if the values didn't matter?

Comment: So you mean if I write  fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05-07:00")) it means different from  fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2007-01-02 15:04:05-07:00"))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From https://golang.org/pkg/time/:

> **func (Time) Format**
>
> func (t Time) Format(layout string) string
>
> Format returns a textual representation of the time value formatted
>   according to layout, which defines the format by showing how the
>   **reference time**, defined to be
>
> `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006`
>
> would be displayed if it were the value;

So you must use the reference time. You should not change it to another time.